# How can I prevent OpenNLP Parser from tokenizing strings?

Tags: parsing, tokenize, opennlp

I need to use OpenNLP Parser for a specific task.  The documentation suggests that you send it tokenized input, which implies that no further tokenization will take place.  However, when I pass a string with parentheses, brackets, or braces, OpenNLP tokenizes them and converts them to PTB tokens.

I don't want this to happen, but I can't figure out how to prevent it.

Specifically, if my input contains "{2}", I want it to stay that way, not become "-LCB- 2 -RCB-".  I now have 3 tokens where I once had one.  I'd also strongly prefer not to have to post-process the output to undo the PTB tokens.

Is there a way to prevent OpenNLP Parser from tokenizing?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the javadocs, there are two parseLine methods, for one a tokenizer can be specified. I haven't tried the following, but I guess training your own tokenizer (https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer.training), which shouldn't be that much of a problem, revert to simple whitespace splitting if need be, and feeding that to the parseLine method (in addition to just the sentence and the number of desired parses should do the trick. E.g. something like the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{  
      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(FileFactory.generateOrCreateFileInstance(<location to en-parser-chunking.bin>)); 
      ParserModel model = new ParserModel(inputStream); 
      Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model); 
      String sentence = "An example with a {2} string.";
      //Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);
      // instead of using the line above, feed it a tokenizer, like so:
      Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, new SimpleTokenizer(), 1);
      for (Parse p : topParses) 
         p.show();          
   }
```

This particular piece of code still splits the { from the 2 in the input, resulting in:

> (TOP (NP (NP (DT An) (NN example)) (PP (IN with) (NP (DT a) (-LRB- -LCB-) (CD 2) (-RRB- -RCB-) (NN string))) (. .)))

but if you train your own tokenizer and don't split on the cases you want to keep as a single token, guess this should work.

Comment: For this task, I'm using a subprocess through Python to call the opennlp binary.  Is there a way to override the tokenizer to use the (provided) whitespace tokenizer from the command line, given that my data is already tokenized?

Comment: Ah ok, haven't used opennlp from the command line a lot, but trying: C:\<...>\apache-opennlp-1.8.1\bin>opennlp Parser
Usage: opennlp Parser [-bs n -ap n -k n -tk tok_model] model < sentences
-bs n: Use a beam size of n.
-ap f: Advance outcomes in with at least f% of the probability mass.
-k n: Show the top n parses.  This will also display their log-probablities.
-tk tok_model: Use the specified tokenizer model to tokenize the sentences. Defaults to a WhitespaceTokenizer. suggests that you can also specify the tokeniser here. (sorry for the crappy formatting)

Comment: Hmm...  I find it hard to believe that it defaults to whitespace tokenizer given that it's tokenizing the input.
In the meantime, I work around the problem by converting the problem characters to entities before parsing, then converting back afterwards.  :-)

Comment: Ha, works too I guess :). I wouldn't be surprised if the WhitespaceTokenizer has a bit of a misleading name in the sense that it doesn't just split on whitespace, but also on punctuation (but, as opposed to more sophisticated tokenisers, doesn't deal with things like $2.50 (and sees that as 3 or 4 tokens, instead of one)). But that's just a hunch, not sure.

Comment: Instead of assuming... just tried:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize("This is a simple example containing {2} ."))); and that gives me: [This, is, a, simple, example, containing, {2}, .] , leaving the {2} as one token. Hmm, weird, not sure why it doesn't work for you from the command line.

Comment: It would be nice if opennlp had some kind of "no tokenize" option, like Stanford's corenlp.  It's fairly evident that despite what the documentation says, the default tokenizer (at least for the command-line tool) for the parser is SimpleTokenizer rahter than WhitespaceTokenizer.